# Under what conditions does Java's Scanner.hasNextLine() block?

Tags: java

The javadoc for `Scanner.hasNextLine()` states:

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
>   This method ***may*** block while waiting for input. The scanner does
>   not advance past any input.

Under what conditions will the method block?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the source that the Scanner gets the input from.

For example, if it's a file, the entire input is available, so `hasNextLine()` wouldn't block (since it can know with certainty when the end of the file is reached and there's no more input.

On the other hand, if the source is standard input, there can always be more input - the user can always type more input - so `hasNextLine()` would block until the user types in a new line of input.

Comment: This is a good answer and explanation of why it works as it does. But it kind of avoids the actual question.

Comment: @aioobe I don't think it avoids the question. When you create a Scanner instance, you know what source it gets the input from, so you know if it would block or not. If you are given a Scanner instance without knowing its source of input, you can't know if it will block.

Comment: @aloobe: You deleted your answer so quickly that I couldn't post this followup comment here, but I wanted to note that your general idea seems sound -- we'd just need a better wrapper class that actually used [`InputStream.available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) to check how many characters it can peek ahead without blocking. (Of course, that will only work in practice if the stream you're reading from actually implements a useful `available()` method; the default implementation just always returns zero.)

Comment: Yeah. Maybe. I still think the bottom line is that deciding whether hasNextLine will block or not isn't a supported use case. If I stumbled across such requirement, I would probably avoid Scanner in the first place, and roll my own class.

Comment: @Eran, you're making assumptions about OP's scenario. Sure, if you have information about the input (such as the type of source, or its content) then you can predict the behavior of method calls such as `hasNextLine`. This may or may not be true in the OPs case. I don't know. I read the OP's question as, how to implement `willCallingHasNextLineOnThisScannerBlock(Scanner s)`, which I still think you avoid answering.

Answer (score 4):

> How to decide if it will block?

To decide if `hasNextLine` will block or not is unfortunately not a supported use case.

This is because the underlying sources doesn't always provide an API for peeking in the stream. Put differently, the implementation of `hasNextLine` calls methods that themselves may block so the problem is sort of inherent.

---

So, what to do?

If this is indeed a required use case, I would recommend one of the following approaches:

- Make sure the conditions are right for the `hasNextLine`. Only provide the scanner with sources that have a definite end (such as a file or string) and never an "open ended" input such as `System.in`.

  If this is part of an API you could wrap the scanner in your own class that only exposes "safe" constructors.
- Roll your own class from scratch that does have a `willHasNextLineBlock` type of method. This could *probably* be implemented somewhat robustly using [InputStream.available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--).

---

Under the category of super ugly workarounds we find:

- Making an attempt at calling `hasNextLine` in a separate thread and see if it returns within reasonable time, as follows:

  ```
  boolean wouldBlock = false;
  Thread t = new Thread(() -> s.hasNextLine());
  t.start();
  try {
      t.join(100);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      wouldBlock = true;
  }
  ```
- Use a custom input stream (*something* like  a [peekable stream](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/147/page2.html) that one could tap into before calling `hasNextLine`. Something like the this

  ```
  CustomStream wrapped = new CustomStream(originalSource)
  Scanner s = new Scanner(wrapped);
  ...
  if (wrapped.hasNextLine())
      // s.hasNextLine would not block
  else
      // s.hasNextLine would block
  ```

  (Note however that this is somewhat unsafe, since the scanner may have buffered some data from the `CustomStream`.)

Comment: Is it really safe to interrupt arbitrary framework code? It might not be hardened against interruption. This might cause internal state to become corrupted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution you suggest will not work, at least not using the PeekableInputStream [implementation](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/147/page2.html) you link to; its `peek()` method calls `InputStream.read()`, which may (and indeed, is explicitly documented to) block until the requested data is available, EOF is reached or an error occurs.

Comment: Great answer, *"Put differently, the implementation of hasNextLine calls methods that themselves may block so the constraint is sort of inherent unfortunately."* this sentence resume it all, that's what I've tried to show pasting the code. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by *"decide if it will block"* you mean that you want to know when it will bock.

Have a look at where the input is assigned in the `hasNextLine` method

```
String result = findWithinHorizon(linePattern(), 0);
```

Now, have a look at the `findWithinHorizon` method

```
public String findWithinHorizon(Pattern pattern, int horizon) {
    ensureOpen();
    if (pattern == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (horizon < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("horizon < 0");
    clearCaches();

    // Search for the pattern
    while (true) { //it may block here if it never break
        String token = findPatternInBuffer(pattern, horizon);
        if (token != null) {
            matchValid = true;
            return token;
        }
        if (needInput)
            readInput();
        else
            break; // up to end of input
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, it will loop infinitely until the end is reached, or until it succeed to read.

`findPatternInBuffer` is a private method of the `Scanner` class that try to read the input.

```
private String findPatternInBuffer(Pattern pattern, int horizon) {
    matchValid = false;
    matcher.usePattern(pattern);
    int bufferLimit = buf.limit();
    int horizonLimit = -1;
    int searchLimit = bufferLimit;
    if (horizon > 0) {
        horizonLimit = position + horizon;
        if (horizonLimit < bufferLimit)
            searchLimit = horizonLimit;
    }
    matcher.region(position, searchLimit);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.hitEnd() && (!sourceClosed)) {
            // The match may be longer if didn't hit horizon or real end
            if (searchLimit != horizonLimit) {
                 // Hit an artificial end; try to extend the match
                needInput = true;
                return null;
            }
            // The match could go away depending on what is next
            if ((searchLimit == horizonLimit) && matcher.requireEnd()) {
                // Rare case: we hit the end of input and it happens
                // that it is at the horizon and the end of input is
                // required for the match.
                needInput = true;
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Did not hit end, or hit real end, or hit horizon
        position = matcher.end();
        return matcher.group();
    }

    if (sourceClosed)
        return null;

    // If there is no specified horizon, or if we have not searched
    // to the specified horizon yet, get more input
    if ((horizon == 0) || (searchLimit != horizonLimit))
        needInput = true;
    return null;
}
```

I posted the whole method to give you a better idea of what I meant by *"succeed to read"*.

Comment: After reading the code, here's my understanding of `hasNextLine()`. The Scanner has an internal buffer to hold the data read from the input source. And a line pattern is used to find a match in this buffer. If a match is not found and more data can be read (i.e. needInput=true), Scanner will keep reading from the input source and feed its internal buffer. It is the `readInput()` method on different input sources may or may not block.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, the *documentation* is the normative specification for the standard API. You can't point at the code of *one* specific implementation and say "look here, this is how it works". I might be running GNU classpath, or apache harmony or whatever.

Comment: @aioobe I believe if only java is tagged we can assume OP refer to standard API ?

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't clear enough. What the standard API is is defined by the Javadoc. There are multiple implementations of the standard API (see for instance [Apache Harmony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Classpath) and [GNU Classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Classpath).) The implementation of Scanner may look different than the implementation you're referring to in your answer. These are still standard complaint Java standard API implementations.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reference. However, if the documentation specify that "it may block" then I assume it will block on any standard API for the same reasons (else I assume each of our answers are wrong). But the, the part of the code where it block would be the same on each API (or maybe not) ?