# Eclipse Hanging on Scanner File Redirection (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I was working on a program that involved taking input from STDIN with the intention of always having the input redirected from a file.  My method of doing so was to use the scanner class to read by line, and perform some string operation.

I am currently doing this in eclipse neon.  I am using the run configurations > common > input file option to automate redirection on running the program and just letting the output print to the console.

What I am finding is that every time I run the program, the code hangs on the last line of the file, and will not terminate until I signal EOF with ctrl+z (windows).  I went back and opened some old projects and noticed the same trend and am confident they didn't have this problem before and haven't changed the code.  Below is a code example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s;
    String everything = "";

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        s = sc.nextLine();
        everything.concat(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println(everything);

    sc.close();

}}
```

It seems like hasNextLine() is blocking as it waits for input, but as I terminate it prints the final line of the file and never prints 'everything'.

Example input file im using looks like:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

The program prints 1, 2, 3 on separate lines, but will not print 4 until I signal EOF. My understanding of hasNextLine() is that when redirected, it should recognize EOF and stop blocking.

EDIT: The problem seems to be independent of hasNextLine() blocking as I am redirecting a file.  hasNextLine() should not block on file redirection as the file should signal EOF.  The problem seems related to eclipse.

Comment: try to increase the memory of eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what conditions does Java's Scanner.hasNextLine() block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235079/under-what-conditions-does-javas-scanner-hasnextline-block)

Comment: I tried changing the options in eclipse.ini, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Not a duplicate as stated above so please do not mark it as such.